# Powershell create iso with defined directories

Tags: powershell

I'm using a function from Alistair McNair (https://github.com/TheDotSource/New-ISOFile/blob/main/New-ISOFile.ps1) as a starting point and trying to add some functionality to it. I would like to create some defined directories on iso that would then hold the data and copy specific data to that directory.

Here is the action to start the process:

```
$btnCreateISO.Add_Click({

 $nicedate = get-date -UFormat %m-%d-%y #put in MM-DD-YY format
 $isotitle = "WSUS-Offline-Server-$nicedate"
 $isofilename = "WSUSSvrOffline-$nicedate.iso" #creates WSUS Offline Server such as update-11-14-2021.iso
 $isofileandpath = $txtISOLocation.text+$isofilename # I:\WSUSSvrOffline-11-23-21.iso
 $WSUSMetaDataPath = "c:\tools\wsusexport\"
 $WSUSContentLocation = $txtWSUSContentLocation.Text # D:\WSUSContent\WsusContent that holds files
 #ProgressBar information
 $ProgressBar.Visible = $true
 $ProgressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 20

 $btnCreateISO.text = "Exporting"
 
 Start-process -FilePath $txtWSUSUtil.text -ArgumentList @("export","$WSUSMetaDataPath\$nicedate-export.xml.gz","$WSUSMetaDataPath\$nicedate-export.log") -Wait

 $btnCreateISO.text = "Exporting Completed"
       
 $btnCreateISO.text = "Creating ISO"
 
 New-ISOFile -WSUSContentLocation $WSUSContentLocation -WSUSMetaDataLocation $WSUSMetaDataPath -destinationIso $isofileandpath -title $isotitle -force -WhatIf

 $btnCreateISO.text = "ISO Created"
```

Here is the code for the function:

...

function New-ISOFile {
#file originall from https://github.com/TheDotSource/New-ISOFile/blob/main/New-ISOFile.ps1 by  Alistair McNair

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,ConfirmImpact="Low")]
Param
(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [string]$WSUSContentLocation,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [string]$WSUSMetaDataLocation,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [string]$destinationIso,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [string]$title = "untitled",
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$false)]
    [switch]$force
  )

begin {

    Write-Verbose ("Function start.")

} # begin

process {

    Write-Verbose ("Processing nested system " + $vmName)

    ## Set type definition
    Write-Verbose ("Adding ISOFile type.")

    $typeDefinition = @'
    public class ISOFile  {
        public unsafe static void Create(string Path, object Stream, int BlockSize, int TotalBlocks) {
            int bytes = 0;
            byte[] buf = new byte[BlockSize];
            var ptr = (System.IntPtr)(&bytes);
            var o = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(Path);
            var i = Stream as System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream;
            if (o != null) {
                while (TotalBlocks-- > 0) {
                    i.Read(buf, BlockSize, ptr); o.Write(buf, 0, bytes);
                }
                o.Flush(); o.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

'@

```
    ## Create type ISOFile, if not already created. Different actions depending on PowerShell version
    if (!('ISOFile' -as [type])) {

        ## Add-Type works a little differently depending on PowerShell version.
        ## https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type
        switch ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major) {

            ## 7 and (hopefully) later versions
            {$_ -ge 7} {
                Write-Verbose ("Adding type for PowerShell 7 or later.")
                Add-Type -CompilerOptions "/unsafe" -TypeDefinition $typeDefinition
            } # PowerShell 7

            ## 5, and only 5. We aren't interested in previous versions.
            5 {
                Write-Verbose ("Adding type for PowerShell 5.")
                $compOpts = New-Object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
                $compOpts.CompilerOptions = "/unsafe"

                Add-Type -CompilerParameters $compOpts -TypeDefinition $typeDefinition
            } # PowerShell 5

            default {
                ## If it's not 7 or later, and it's not 5, then we aren't doing it.
                throw ("Unsupported PowerShell version.")

            } # default

        } # switch

    } # if


    ## Initialise image
    Write-Verbose ("Initialising image object.")
    try {
        $image = New-Object -ComObject IMAPI2FS.MsftFileSystemImage -Property @{VolumeName=$title} -ErrorAction Stop

        Write-Verbose ("initialised.")
    } # try
    catch {
        throw ("Failed to initialise image. " + $_.exception.Message)
    } # catch


    ## Create target ISO, throw if file exists and -force parameter is not used.
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($destinationIso)) {

        if (!($targetFile = New-Item -Path $destinationIso -ItemType File -Force:$Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
            throw ("Cannot create file " + $destinationIso + ". Use -Force parameter to overwrite if the target file already exists.")
        } # if

    } # if


    ## Get WSUSMetaData content from specified path
    Write-Verbose ("Fetching items from WSUSMetaData directory.")
    try {
        $WSUSMetaData = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $WSUSMetaDataLocation -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Verbose ("Got WSUSMetaData items.")
    } # try
    catch {
        throw ("Failed to get WSUSMetaData items. " + $_.exception.message)
    } # catch

    ## Get WSUSMetaData content from specified path
    Write-Verbose ("Fetching items from WSUSContentData directory.")
    try {
        $WSUSContentData = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $WSUSContentLocation -ErrorAction Stop

        Write-Verbose ("Got WSUSContentData items.")
    } # try
    catch {
        throw ("Failed to get WSUSContentData items. " + $_.exception.message)
    } # catch

    ##Create Directories on the ISO for the content
    ## Both the WSUSMetaData files go into this directory on the iso
    $DirWSUSMetaData = $image.CreateDirectoryItem("WSUSMetaData")
    $DirWSUSMetaData = $image.Root.AddTree($WSUSMetaDataLocation,$true)
    
    ## Add the WSUSMetaData to our image
    Write-Verbose ("Adding WSUSMetaData to image.")
    foreach($file in $WSUSMetaDataLocation){
       try {
         $image.Root.AddTree($file.fullname, $true)
       } 
       catch {
         throw ("Faile to add" + $file.fullname + ". " + $_.exeption.message)
       }
    }


    ##All the WSUSContent directories go into this directory on the iso
    $DirWSUSContent = $image.CreateDirectoryItem("WSUSContentData") #create the directory WSUSContentData to hold all WSUS Content in the ISO
    $DirWSUSContent = $image.Root.AddTree($WSUSContentLocation,$true) #add the location of the content to copy


    ## Add the WSUSMetaData to our image
    Write-Verbose ("Adding WSUSMetaData to image.")

    foreach($file in $WSUSContentLocation) {

        try {
            $image.Root.AddTree($file.FullName, $true)
        } # try
        catch {
            throw ("Failed to add " + $file.fullname + ". " + $_.exception.message)
        } # catch

    } # foreach

    ## Write out ISO file
    Write-Verbose ("Writing out ISO file to " + $targetFile)

    try {
        $result = $image.CreateResultImage()
        [ISOFile]::Create($targetFile.FullName,$result.ImageStream,$result.BlockSize,$result.TotalBlocks)
    } # try
    catch {
        throw ("Failed to write ISO file. " + $_.exception.Message)
    } # catch

    Write-Verbose ("File complete.")

    ## Return file details
    return $targetFile

} # process

end {
    Write-Verbose ("Function complete.")
} # end
```

...

Getting an error when I'm trying to create it:

```
What if: Performing the operation "New-ISOFile" on target " WSUSSvrOffline-11-23-21.iso".
Adding '11-23-21-export.xml.gz' would result in a result image having a size larger than the current configured limit.
At C:\tools\WSUSPowerShellStuff\WSUSOfflineServerGUIv1.ps1:153 char:9
+         $DirWSUSMetaData = $image.Root.AddTree($WSUSMetaDataLocation, ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
 
Faile to add. 
At C:\tools\WSUSPowerShellStuff\WSUSOfflineServerGUIv1.ps1:162 char:14
+ ...             throw ("Faile to add" + $file.fullname + ". " + $_.exepti ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Faile to add. :String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Faile to add.
```

So how do you change the configured limit?

[Files Size of file giving error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iRjs.png)

Comment: Is there a reason that your posted version of New-ISOFile and [the one you linked in your question](https://github.com/TheDotSource/New-ISOFile/blob/main/New-ISOFile.ps1) are different functions?

Comment: From what I can tell, the function on GitHub first instances an [IFileSystemImage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imapi2fs/nn-imapi2fs-ifilesystemimage) and then calls [ChooseImageDefaultsForMediaType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imapi2fs/nf-imapi2fs-ifilesystemimage-chooseimagedefaultsformediatype) with a value of 13 since the default is `DVDPLUSRW_DUALLAYER`. That sets the `FreeMediaBlocks` property of the image to 0, which the doc says is "unlimited". So my guess is that the function you're using is broken. Try getting it from GitHub & try again.

Comment: I was using the New-ISOFile as a starting point, I need to have 2 defined directories on the iso file, so when I go and import things, they are from a static directory.

Comment: Well, did you call `ChooseImageDefaultsForMediaType`? I don't see where you did. [The doc says default size is a 650 MB CD-R](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imapi2fs/nf-imapi2fs-ifilesystemimage-put_freemediablocks). You can't put a 1.2 GB file on a 650 MB CD.